# nhibernate intercept select query

Tags: nhibernate, interceptor, select-query

I'm looking at the nhibernate interceptor. It seems to be able to intercept save, update and delete queries but is there anyway I can intercept a select query.

The problem I have is that I automatically want to append some additional sql filters to the executing sql statement in certain cases.

Any thoughts

Thanks
Mat

Answer (score 2):

The interceptor framework only allows you to intercept entity operations like save, update, and delete. Queries themselves aren't intercepted, only entity operations (and selecting/viewing doesn't count).

Consider using some sort of inheritance for a set of query classes that append to your ICriteria to suit your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish that with a custom NHibernate persister; however, I'm having trouble finding examples on how you'd write one...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `where` attribute on the `class` tag:

```
<class name="MyClass" where="deleted=0">
    ...
</class>
```

Comment: @mjmcloug: True.  I actually opted *not* to put this kind of logic in the mapping, and I put it in a `SoftDeletableRepository` which offers extra functionality over `Repository`: `SoftDelete`, `DeletedEntities` and `Entities` (there was already an `AllEntities` on the `Repository` class).  The derived repository handles anything that implements `ISoftDeletable`.